# Expressing $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{z^3-n^3}$ in closed form

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I want to express $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{z^3-n^3}$$ in closed form.

I know that $$\pi z\cot(\pi z)=1+2z^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{z^2-n^2}$$ which looks close, but I don’t know how to use it.

Comment: Is there a reason you think there is a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, because it's an exercise in a complex analysis book (where the formula for $\pi z\cot(\pi z)$ that I mentioned is given)

Comment: This sum may be evaluated using the residue theorem; as the summand is relatively simple, there is most likely a useful closed form.

Comment: @RonGordon I know how to find an integral using the residue theorem, but I've never done an infinite sum like this before. Could you please show how it goes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum may be evaluated using the residue theorem.  Basically, one considers the integral

$$\oint_C dw \, \pi \, \cot{\pi w} \, f(w)$$

where $f(w) = (z^3-w^3)^{-1}$, and $C$ is a rectangular contour with vertices $$\pm (N+1/2) (1\pm i) $$

taken in a counterclockwise sense.  To summarize: the contour integral is zero (the contributions vanish sufficiently fast as $N \to \infty$ - thanks, @markoriedel.  See pages 76-78 of [this reference](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis_part7.pdf) for a full derivation.)), but is also equal to the sum of the residues at the poles.  The poles of the cotangent are at the integers, so that we have

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \pi \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{w=w_k} [\cot{\pi w} \, f(w)]$$

With the $f(w)$ we have, the poles are at $w=z$ and $w=z e^{\pm i 2 \pi/3}$.  As all the poles are simple, we have

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{w=z} \frac{\pi \, \cot{\pi w}}{z^3-w^3} = -\frac{\cot{\pi z}}{3 z^2}$$

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{w=z e^{i 2 \pi/3}} \frac{\pi \, \cot{\pi w}}{z^3-w^3} = -\frac{\cot{\left (\pi z e^{i 2 \pi/3}\right )}}{3 z^2 e^{-i 2 \pi/3}}$$

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{w=z e^{-i 2 \pi/3}} \frac{\pi \, \cot{\pi w}}{z^3-w^3} = -\frac{\cot{\left (\pi z e^{-i 2 \pi/3}\right )}}{3 z^2 e^{i 2 \pi/3}}$$

So we just need to sum these up.  The challenge is essentially evaluating the cotangent of the complex number, but it is straightforward and the rest is just algebra.

Note that we can express the result as

$$\frac{\pi}{3 z^2} \left [\cot{\pi z} + 2 \Re{\left [\cot{\left ( \pi z e^{i 2 \pi/3}\right ) e^{i 2 \pi/3}} \right ]} \right ] $$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{\pi}{3 z^2} \left [\cot (\pi  z)+\frac{\sin (\pi  z)+\sqrt{3} \sinh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  z\right)}{\cosh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  z\right)-\cos(\pi  z)}\right ]$$

or, finally,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^3-n^3} = \frac{2 \pi}{3 z^2} \frac{\sqrt{3} \sin (\pi  z) \sinh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  z\right)+\cos(\pi  z) \cosh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  z\right)-\cos (2 \pi  z)}{2 \sin (\pi  z) \cosh \left(\sqrt{3} \pi  z\right)-\sin (2 \pi  z)} $$

Here's a plot for $z \in [0.1,0.9]$ for both the expression above and a numerical approximation to the sum just to make sure:

[image]

Comment: Amazingly fast and quality as always. Upvoted.

Comment: I don't think you have cancellation on opposite sides of your rectangle, that does not match the symmetry of the problem. There may be no avoiding a bound on the line integrals (which is easy because the order of $1/(z^3-w^3)$ goes to $1/N^3.$)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: yes, you are right, I stand corrected.  I will make the edit.  Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, you might want to typeset those bounds as the OP might not be convinced by just looking at it. These are just my humble 2cts.

Comment: Better yet, I'll provide a reference so I can get back to work!

Comment: Could one not use residue calculus and the last identity to work out $\zeta(3)$ (that is, the same way $\zeta(2)$ can be obtained using residue calculus)?

Comment: @Alyosha: that won't work because the symmetry is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

First rewrite it as:

$$\frac{1}{z^3} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z^3-n^3} + \frac{1}{z^3+n^3}\right) = \frac{1}{z^3} +\sum_1^\infty \frac{2z^3}{z^6-n^6}$$

so we only need to find:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^6-n^6}$$

Now, if $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity, there are functions $a(u),b(u),c(u)$ such that for real $u\neq v$:

$$\frac{1}{u^3-v^3} = \frac{a(u)}{u-v} +\frac{b(u)}{\omega u -v} + \frac{c(u)}{\omega^2u-v}$$

Setting $u=z^2$ and $v=n^2$, and finding a solution $\zeta$ so that $\zeta^2=\omega$, then we have:

$$\frac{1}{z^6-n^6} = \frac{a(z^2)}{z^2 - n^2}+\frac{b\left((\zeta z)^2\right)}{(\zeta z)^2-n^2} + \frac{c\left((\zeta^2 z)^2\right)}{(\zeta^2 z)^2 -n^2}$$

So we can use your first result to find:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^6-n^6} = a(z^2)f(z) + b(\zeta^2z^2)f(\zeta z) + c(\zeta^4 z^2)f(\zeta^2 z)$$
where $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2-n^2} = \frac{\pi z\cot(\pi z)-1}{2z^2}$$
That seems a bit messy, and requires jumping into complex numbers...

Comment: Fixed. The $a,b,c$ are not constants, but functions of $u$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are referring to the book by Ahlfors, here is a method relying on it:

Starting with a partial fraction decomposition w.r.t. $n$ we find

$$\frac{1}{z^3-n^3}=\frac{ \rho_3^0}{3z^2} \frac{1}{ \rho_3^0 z-n}+\frac{\rho_3^1}{3z^2} \frac{1}{ \rho_3 z-n}+\frac{\rho_3^2}{3z^2} \frac{1}{ \rho_3^2 z-n} $$ where $\rho_3=\exp(2 \pi i/3)$. Using the formula $$ \pi \cot( \pi z)= \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=-m}^m \frac{1}{z-n} $$
from page 189 three times should give you the desired result. I will add that since the series converges in the usual sense, it also converges w.r.t. this "principal value summation".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a closed form by Maple

> $$ \frac{2}{3}\,{\frac {\pi \, \left( -\cos \left( 2\,\pi \,z \right) +\sqrt {3}
> \sin \left( \pi \,z \right) \sinh \left( \pi \,z\sqrt {3} \right) +
> \cos \left( \pi \,z \right) \cosh \left( \pi \,z\sqrt {3} \right) 
>  \right) }{{z}^{2} \left( 2\,\sin \left( \pi \,z \right) \cosh \left( 
> \pi \,z\sqrt {3} \right) -\sin \left( 2\,\pi \,z \right)  \right) }}.$$

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: Not my downvote (though sorely tempted), but Maple output is usually not appreciated.  Understanding of how such a sum may be derived is.  Follow the debate here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11723/are-answers-that-have-no-explanations-useful?cb=1

Comment: @RonGordon: Still, it is not a valid reason for downvoting. I do not think we are joking on this website and wasting our time. It takes time and effort from us. It is the responsibility of the people who are taking care of this website to tell us what's going on here.

Comment: Large portions of the Math.SE community would vigorously disagree with you.  What time and effort?  You punched in the sum into Maple, it gave you output, you typed into MathJAX.  Hardly a shining example of the mathematical leadership to which we look.  The people I know who get upvotes on problems like these spend hours deriving every step by hand and then rearranging so that it tells a good story.

Comment: @RonGordon: It is their right. However, it is a valid answer and it assures that there is a closed form for the problem. Ron Gordon, please stop taking no sense.

Comment: May I comment here. This sum can be evaluated by the $\pi\cot(\pi x)$ multiplier technique. I would do it but I lack the courage to enter in competition with amazingly fast people (much faster than I am) who answer before I do, making my effort redundant. ;-)

Comment: So you expect your peers to upvote your ability to punch characters into a computer and translate the output into MathJAX.  I just want to make sure I am understanding you.  Well, at least you tell us where the answer come from, that's an improvement over @Cleo.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You should post your answer. I just wanted to let people know that there is a closed form. I have alot of worded out problems, but not all the time we have the energy and time to do so. We should not depreciate other people work.

Comment: @Marko, I'd like to see that answer.

Comment: @Mhenni : Don't worry about it, down vote has nothing to do with the value of your answer but the perception of someone of it. I had seen correct answers being downvoted and then up voted later.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That will no longer be necessary. ;-)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: These kinds of sums are classical and can be tackled by complex variable techniques as pointed out by the OP. However, we can use other techniques to find them.

Comment: As usual Mhenni, we agree to disagree.